# How to delete duplicate copies on mapping element counter?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a little project where I can count the number of elements in an array. This part I have already done. My question is how can I fix a counting problem? I'm using a mapping method to get my element occurrence counter, but I want to put the data into an array. The only way I know how is to take the data from the mapping with .get. They way I'm doing it is by using this first part here:

```
let winners = [1, 2, 3, 2];
let nullArray = [];
let mode = new Map([...new Set(winners)].map(
    k => [k, winners.filter(t => t === k).length]
));
for (let n in winners) {
    nullArray.push(mode.get(winners[n]));
    console.log(nullArray);
}
```

However, this will *n push matches. Like, if you have l=[1,2,2], because l[1]=2, and l[2]=2, they will be pushed into the nullArray as 2, however, it will also push l[2] and l[1] as the values are different. If you have three matches, it would duplicate 3 times, and so on. To counter this, I tried making a detector that would calculate when the same numbers in the nullArray are from the same copy but in a different order. To do this, I used the code I have below (combined with the original code)

```
let winners = [1, 2, 3, 2];
let nullArray = [];
let mode = new Map([...new Set(winners)].map(
    k => [k, winners.filter(t => t === k).length]
));
for (let n in winners) {
    nullArray.push(mode.get(winners[n]));
    console.log(nullArray);
}
for (let num in nullArray) {
    for (let c in nullArray) {
        if (nullArray[num] === nullArray[c] && winners[num] === winners[c]) {
            nullArray.splice(num, 1);
        }
        console.log(nullArray);
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try this, the specific output on this array is [2,2]. How could I make a general solution that will eliminate all duplicate copies, only leaving a single copy of the number count (which in the case of  [1,2,3,2], I would want nullArray=[1,2,1] as an output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

If you don't care about the order, you can just do the following.

```js
const remove_dup_and_count = (winners = [1, 2, 3, 2]) =>{
let map = {}
//count elements 
for (let n in winners) {
    const curr_val = winners[n]
    //duplicate, so we increment count
    if(curr_val in map) map[curr_val] += 1
    //first seen, so we start at 1
    else map[curr_val] = 1    
}
//lets grab the array of all keys in map
const keys_arr = Object.keys(map)
let count_arr = []
for(let i of keys_arr){
  count_arr.push(map[i])
}
return count_arr
}
console.log(remove_dup_and_count())
```

If you care about the order, this is your best bet:

```js
 const remove_dup_and_count = (winners = [1, 2, 3, 2]) =>{
    let map = new Map()
    //count elements 
    for (let n in winners) {
        const curr_val = winners[n]
        //duplicate, so we increment count
        if(map.get(curr_val)) map.set(curr_val, map.get(curr_val) + 1)
        //first seen, so we start at 1
        else map.set(curr_val,1)    
    }
    let count_arr = []
    //lets grab the array of all keys in map
    for (const [key, value] of map) {
      count_arr.push(value)
    }
    return count_arr
   }
    console.log(remove_dup_and_count())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use .reduce() method and then retrieve how many times the value is repeated in array using map.values(); something like the following snippet:

```
const winners = [1, 2, 3, 2];
const mapWinners = winners.reduce((winnersAccumulator, singleWinner) => winnersAccumulator.set(singleWinner, (winnersAccumulator.get(singleWinner) || 0) + 1), new Map())
console.log([...mapWinners.values()])
```